# Error when Compiling with Web Compiler 2022+: "The system cannot find the specified path"

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, sass, web-compiler

I have been on this problem for quite some time.

I am using **Web Compiler 2022+ 1.14.11**

And **Visual Studio 17.8.5**

For some reason suddenly the **Web Compiler won't compile my scss file** anymore.

Im getting the **error in the Task Runner Explorer**:

```
A:\Projekte\Privat\...\src\...\...> 
c:\users\simon müller\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\17.0_899cbc51\extensions\bubxkjzz.tnk\WebCompiler.exe 
"A:/Projekte/Privat/.../src/.../.../compilerconfig.json" "wwwroot/css/app/test.scss"

Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Process terminated with code 1.
```

The error message is in German. I translated it to English:
**The system cannot find the specified path.**

I have seen similar problems on the internet, and also tried many solution that all did not help.

**I have tried:**

- Reinstalling Web Compiler extension
- Clearing `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp`

**I found a solution** on [GitHub](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/390#issuecomment-475427735) to execute the `prepare.cmd batch script` in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.14.11` but this folder **does no contain any file**.

I have also made sure that my Windows user has permission for all the folders (compilerconfig.json, localtemp, test.scss).

I have created a new scss file (test.scss) to test if it is a problem with the syntax or something. It only contains one stlye:

```
#test{
    background: green;
}
```

Anyone have a solution?

Thank you for your help.

Simon

Comment: I suggest you could try to delete the output .css file. Right clicked on the source .scss file. Selected "Recompile file". The output .css file was recreated.

Comment: I have tried that. Did not work.